# Find the sum-of-products expansions of the following Boolean function?

Tags: function, boolean, replit

how to get rid of this message in replit.com?
I am able to run the code but i get this message in console for every single line of code that I print.
Anyone that has the same problem or know to remove this without breaking the console?
I have tried to create new REPL, checked the settings , refresh , loged in and out but still the error is there.

--> poetry lock --no-update
Resolving dependencies...

Comment: Update- after a few more research and replit documentation I manage to find the answer and want to let everyon know. Basically I went to the 3 dots next to my files folder on top left corner and pressed unhide the hidden files, which will open the Config files. I added this line of code on top :" disableInstallBeforeRun = true" and it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Update- after a few more research and replit documentation I manage to find the answer and want to let everyon know. Basically I went to the 3 dots next to my files folder on top left corner and pressed unhide the hidden files, which will open the Config files. I added this line of code on top :" disableInstallBeforeRun = true" and it solved the problem